# Most efficient Python code for finding reference angles?

Tags: python, performance, reference, angle

Here is what I created below.
   There has to be a more efficient way for my daughter who is a
   beginning coder to implement this. What is the most efficient
   methodology for coding this ? I especially would like to see a better 
   way to code what I call caseVII (negative angles less than -360)
   HELP???

## PYTHON CODE FOR FINDING A REFERENCE ANGLE IN DEGREES by Lee S.

import math

```
angle = float (input("Enter angle(deg) to calculate reference angle for : "))
#CASE 1 (<90 and > 0)
def caseI(angle):
angle=angle
print("Reference Angle = ",angle)

return (angle)


def caseII(angle):
#CASE II (>90 and <=180 )
angle=180.00-angle
print("Reference Angle = ",angle)
return (angle)

def caseIII(angle):
#CASEIII(>180 and <=270)
angle=angle-180.0
CASEIV(>270 and <360)
angle=360.00-angle
print("Reference Angle = ",angle)
return (angle)

def caseV(angle):
#CASEVI(>360 )
angle=(angle/360 - int (angle/360))*360
if angle >=0 and  angle <= 90:
   angle=angle
elif angle >90 and angle <=180:
   angle=180.0-angle
elif angle >180 and angle <=270:
   angle=angle-180.0
elif angle >270 and angle <=360:
   angle=360.00-angle    

print("Reference Angle = ",angle)  


return (angle)


def caseVI(angle):
#CASE (<0 and <=-360)
angle = angle+360
if angle >=0 and  angle <= 90:
   angle=angle
elif angle >90 and angle <=180:
   angle=180.0-angle
elif angle >180 and angle <=270:
   angle=angle-180.0
elif angle >270 and angle <=360:
   angle=360.00-angle 
print("Reference Angle = ",angle)
return (angle)

def caseVII(angle):
#CASE7 (<-360 there has to be a more efficient way????)
angle=(angle/360 + abs(int (angle/360))*360)
angle = angle+360
if angle >=0 and  angle <= 90:
   angle=angle
elif angle >90 and angle <=180:
   angle=180.0-angle
elif angle >180 and angle <=270:
   angle=angle-180.0
elif angle >270 and angle <=360:
   angle=360.00-angle
print("Reference Angle = ",angle)
return (angle)

if angle >=0 and  angle <= 90:
 caseI(angle)

elif angle >90 and angle <=180:
caseII(angle)

elif angle >180 and angle <=270:

caseIII(angle)

elif angle >270 and angle <=360:
caseIV(angle)

elif angle >360:
caseV(angle)

elif angle <0 and angle >=-360:
caseVI(angle)

else:
caseVII(angle)
```

Comment: If you are looking for recommendations of how to make your code better (more efficient, more pythonic, etc), I might suggest [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). In the meantime, would you mind fixing your indentation?

Comment: Please re-take the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Asking for a code review and overhaul is out of scope here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in two steps

```
angle = float (input("Enter angle(deg) to calculate reference angle for : "))
angle = angle%180
if angle > 90 :
    angle = 180 - angle
print("Reference Angle = ",angle)
```